# Join/Merge for finding specific values with Panda in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, join

I want to define parent and child relationship between 10,000 rows of csv files with Panda in python.
I have below values and I just want to add a new columns as Parent and Child:

- If the Name consists of Captain, it will be the parent. ( the code is perfectly work in this regard.)
- Now for defining child I use join, If the Team of parent is equal to any other row that row will be the child .
  I update my code as below:
  and from the first code I have got the **error** which has been determined.
  and for the second code the rows are **duplicated** and wrong.

CSV File :

```
Name                TEAM
Captain                A
replace-Captain1       A
replace-Captain2       -
replace-Captain3       -
Captain                B
replace-Captain4       B
replace-Captain5       B
 ...                   …
```

Expected CSV:

```
Parent          ParentTEAM        Child                 ChildTEAM
Captain            A           replace-Captain1             A
Captain            B           replace-Captain4             B
Captain            B           replace-Captain5             B
```

First Code:

*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\FamilyMembers.csv")
df["Parent"] = np.where(df['Name'].str.contains('Captain'), df['Name'], "-")
if pd.isnull(df["TEAM"]):
    df = df.join(df.set_index(['TEAM'])['Name'].rename('Child'), on=['TEAM'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\FamilyMembers-Final.csv')
```

- 

```
Error: Exception has occurred: ValueError The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Second Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\FamilyMembers.csv")
df["Parent"] = np.where(df['Name'].str.contains('Captain'), df['Name'], "-")

df = df.join(df.set_index(['TEAM'])['Name'].rename('Child'), on=['TEAM'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\FamilyMembers-Final.csv')
```

Result of second code:

```
    Parent                 ParentTEAM      Child                 ChildTEAM
    Captain                   A           Captain                   A
    Captain                   A           replace-Captain1          A
replace-Captain1              A           replace-Captain1          A
replace-Captain1              A           replace-Captain1          A
    Captain                   B           Captain                   B

    Captain                   B           replace-Captain4          B

replace-Captain4              B           replace-Captain1          B

replace-Captain4              B           replace-Captain4          B
```

Comment: what is the question about regex?

Comment: I thought maybe with regular expression it is possible to find out the parent and for child with the relation of parent and child amybe I am wrong. I updated the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not very clear what you are trying to do, perhaps this:

```py
>>> parent = df[df.Name=='Captain']
>>> parent.columns = ['Parent','ParentTEAM']
>>> parent
    Parent ParentTEAM
0  Captain          A
4  Captain          B

>>> child = df[df.Name.str.contains('-') & ~(df.TEAM=='-')]
>>> child.columns = ['Child', 'ChildTEAM']
>>> child
              Child ChildTEAM
1  replace-Captain1         A
5  replace-Captain4         B
6  replace-Captain5         B

>>> pd.merge(parent, child, left_on='ParentTEAM', right_on='ChildTEAM')
    Parent ParentTEAM             Child ChildTEAM
0  Captain          A  replace-Captain1         A
1  Captain          B  replace-Captain4         B
2  Captain          B  replace-Captain5         B
```

Comment: Thanks avloss, the child determination is not as I mentioned. The rule of child determination is about having the same TEAM as Captain. forexample in this sample Captain is parent , Captain is in TEAM A so replace_Captain1 will be the child. the team should be checked for child determination.

Comment: unfortunately this still is not clear to me, there's no `IP` columns. Perhaps you might update your example with a few extra rows.

Comment: I just correct my comment. It is about TEAM. If the teams are the same.

Comment: As you see my samples replace-Captain1 is in TEAM A so we have determined parent which has Captain in Name, the TEAM of Captain is A so any other row which is in A team is the child.

Comment: Isn't your `Expected CSV:` example wrong then, `replace-Captain2` should be `replace-Captain4`. Is the output above wrong?

Comment: NO, replace4 and replace5 is the child of captain.

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure I can help.

Comment: Many Thanks for time you spend. just for more clarification Captain is in Team A and B and parent. replace-Captain1 is the child of Captain. Also replace-Captain4 and replace-Captain5 is the child of Captain too. due to the team.

Comment: from your help I find out the answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I found out the answer:

```
Parent= df[df['Name'].str.contains('Captain')]
print(Parent)
Child= df[df['Name'].str.contains('Captain')]
print(Child)
result = pd.merge(Parent, Child, left_on='TEAM', right_on='TEAM')
```